# Lucene custom similarity based on number of matching terms

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Lucene to calculate the number of matching terms between the query string and each document in the corpus.

For example,

*the given query, "a b c d d"*

the document 1: "a b"

the document 2: "c c"

**I want the similarity scores to be:**

document 1 is 2

document 2 is 1

At first, I thought it is a simple task because I can just override the DefaultSimilarity() as the following:

```
Similarity similarity = new DefaultSimilarity() {

        @Override
        public float lengthNorm(FieldInvertState state) {
            return 1.0f;
        }

        @Override
        public float coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap) {
            return 1.0f;
        }

        @Override
        public float idf(long docFreq, long numDocs) {
            return 1.0f;
        }

        @Override
        public float queryNorm(float sumOfSquaredWeights) {
            return 1.0f;
        }   

        @Override
        public float tf(float freq) {
            return freq == 0f ? 0f : 1f;
        }
};
```

This way, my similarity score can be interpreted as (pseudo code):

```
Similarity(query, document):
    score = 0
    for each term t in my query:
         if document contains term t:
              score += 1
    return score
```

Unfortunately, this is not an expected behavior!

From my previous example and I add the third document:

*the given query, "a b c d d"*

the document 1: "a b"

the document 2: "c c"

the document 3: "d e g"

**The similarity score are:**

document 1 is 2 (1 match for a, 1 match for b)

document 2 is 1 (1 match for c)

document 3 is 2 ! (1 match for d and another match for the same d!)

This is wrong. The similarity score for this query and document 3 is 1.

My question is how can implement this similarity class in Lucene? I can do it easily by writing my own Java code but I have around 2000 unique queries and roughly 10,000,0000 documents. I need to take advantage of Lucene indexing.

Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: what kind of query you are using? I could easily show the solution to get this, but need some more details to write correct and good answer

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am trying to compute the number of matching terms between two documents. I use bag-of-words to represent a document. I indexed my 10 million documents as my training document using Lucene indexer. Then, my query is a testing document. It can be very long query (~500 words total). Did I provide you enough information? Thanks again.